# Include the Project Root Path with Zetzer

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I am a newbie to Grunt and I am stuck with something. Would be great if someone can help me out.

In the GruntJs file, every other "task" gets the path relative to the "base" or "project root" by default. That's great. But, how do I get the same ( base / project root ) value passed to the Zetzer's env paths ( path_img, path_js, path_css ). These are used in doT files  ( .dot.htm )

When the ( .htm after grunting ) file is called, these path are produced relative to the html file itself.

Is there someway to include the project root to the path. ( without manually typing it in )

Code :

```
 module.exports = function (grunt) {

// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),




    zetzer: {
        main: {
            options: {
                env: {
                    path_img:   "<%= pkg.url %>/site/img",
                    path_css:   "<%= pkg.url %>/css",
                    path_js:    "<%= pkg.url %>/js",
                    path_root : "<%= pkg.url %>/tmp"
                },
                partials: "templates/partials",
                templates: "templates"
            },
```

Let me know if I need to be more clear.

Thanks.